# Nodeclipse does not recognize other scripts in DOM

Tags: javascript, node.js, eclipse, nodeclipse

We created a Node.js fileserver who answers requests with the appropiate file in a folder called "web". Inside this folder there are three files: game.htm, game.js and three.min.js (a 3D game library)

Snippet of HTML body:

```
<body>
    <script src="three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="game.js"></script>
</body>
```

Now the Nodeclipse validator throws dozens of warnings in the game.js file saying that the objects of the library (three.min.js) I use are undefined. However, if I run the server and load the game.htm everything works like a charm. So the only problem is that the Nodeclipse tools don't know that the two files are later combined in the HTML file. The problem is that I don't have autocompletion and complete validation of my code. How can I fix that?

Comment: This is general Eclipse (more exactly WTP question)